# Return integers

Tags: coldfusion, duck-typing

I have been reviewing asm.js, and I know one of the thing it does is use bit-wise operations to force numbers to be integers

If instead of

```
<cfreturn x>
```

If I

```
<cfreturn BitOr(x,0)>
```

Does this ensure that I am returning only integers as opposed to a float representation of an integer?

Comment: Perhaps another possibility would be to take the returned value in JavaScript and apply `parseInt(variable_name,10)` to it before further processing.

Comment: FYI: You can always check the type of a variable by calling `.getClass().getName()` on it.

Comment: After running Adam's suggestion, I see that it returns `java.lang.Integer`

Comment: Given that the docs say the function operates on two 32 bit *integers*, the result would have to be an integer too.  (Like with most things, I would bet CF truncates/converts the input to an integer first if needed.)

Comment: BTW, the other suggestions are a more straightforward way to ensure you get an integer, but I am pretty certain `BitOr` always returns an integer too, FWIW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JavaCast()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/JavaCast) to ensure that only integers are returned from ColdFusion.

```
<cfreturn JavaCast( "int", x )>
```

Depending on the version of ColdFusion, you may have an issue with serializeJSON() converting that value to a string though. In that case, then Miguel's suggestion of using parseInt() in your JavaScript would apply.